# Neural Language Model: Getting error - ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 380 into shape (1,1,10)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, nlm

I am trying to follow a tutorial on character based Neural Language Model, which attempts to predict "words in a sequence based on the specific words".

As instructed, I have generated the sequence of texts to a file, defined the language model and saved the model as well as the mapping characters (as `*.pkl`).

Next in order to generate texts (using the saved mapping), encoded the texts to integers and run the code for predicting characters in sequence using `predict_classes()`. Using the following function (code below) to predict a *sequence of characters* using *seed text*.

However I am running into the following error when I run the script:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 380 into shape (1,1,10)

This is the part where I am getting the error:

```
def generate_seq(model, mapping, seq_length, seed_text, n_chars):
    in_text = seed_text
    # generate a fixed number of characters
    for _ in range(n_chars):
        # encode the characters as integers
        encoded = [mapping[char] for char in in_text]
        # truncate sequences to a fixed length
        encoded = pad_sequences([encoded], maxlen=seq_length, truncating='pre')
        # one hot encode
        encoded = to_categorical(encoded, num_classes=len(mapping))
        encoded = encoded.reshape(1, encoded.shape[0], encoded.shape[1]) # <--- Error line
        # predict character
        yhat = model.predict_classes(encoded, verbose=0)
        # reverse map integer to character
        out_char = ''
        for char, index in mapping.items():
            if index == yhat:
                out_char = char
                break
        # append to input
        in_text += out_char
    return in_text
```

The function is being called with:

```
print(generate_seq(model, mapping, 10, 'Sing a son', 20))
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: can you share the shape of encoded after you run pad_sequences(), and each line that follows ? Looks like the size after padding is altered but with no visibility into what it is vsv what size the model expects it may be hard to see why

Comment: It shows `[[12 23 27 21  1 15  1 32 28 27]]`. Which I suppose, represent each token (*character*) in the trained model.

Comment: Found the solution. 
**1.** **Comment out** the line with `encoded = encoded.reshape(1, encoded.shape[0], encoded.shape[1])` completely and it works without the *ValueError*.
**OR**
**2.** Change the code line to: `encoded = encoded.reshape(-1, encoded.shape[1], encoded.shape[2])` - *Also works!*

Comment: ah great, that was the issue then